# superimposed histograms in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I know how to make histograms but I wanted to reproduce this image:

[image: Imgur]

The original is form a PNAS (journal) paper by Andrew Karplus et al. 2011.

I have the following image from my own histogram:

[image]

I have the following questions:

1) How can I start the plot with histogram smoothed out?

2) How can I superimpose but yet not distort the color as I have done in my plot (2nd image), that is omit the points in the exterior  plot that are in the interior one as well to produce a clean superimposition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `fill_between`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def gaussian(x, x0, y0, variance):
    return y0 * np.exp(-(x - x0) ** 2 / variance)

x = np.linspace(150, 210, 100)
plt.fill_between(x, 0, gaussian(x, 180, 5000, 30), color='red', zorder=0)
plt.fill_between(x, 0, gaussian(x, 181, 4500, 10), color='blue', zorder=1)

plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

---

Above I used `gaussian` to generate a substitute for your data; you can replace `gaussian(...)` with your actual histogram values.